# How can I make a webpage compatible on both 1920px and 1366px (laptop) screen size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am developing one website where the requirements are 1920 * 1080px. There are five sections in total and each of them would be the same specs (1920 in width and 1080 in height). I did not use bootstrap container as it's width is 960px and also using container-fluid I am not able to get the expected output. So I set the width and height of each div in scss and the page looks good on 1920px screen size. But when I open it in my laptop, it gets cropped really bad. I am also using multiple images, overlays with position and z-index properties.
The html structure is as below:

```
<div id="page_index">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div id="one">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
      <!-- Here are the contents -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <!-- div id=two, three, four, five goes here -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Here are the examples of one div where I set the height and width:

```
#one {
    background-color: $g_color_blue_promotion;
    width: 1920px;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 1080px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}
```

In this case, what should be the best to make it fit for both screen sizes? Note that, this page is not required to be responsive but at least, the user should be able to view it on both of the screen sizes.

Comment: Use [**Media Queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Reconsider your approach. There are many things you can use in CSS like `vw` and `vh` and flexbox. Also, the fact that you're using Bootstrap should make a lot easier.

Answer (score -2):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

use this on yous JS file header.

Comment: Use this but not on your JS file. Use in your HTML file's header.